# Intent action when data is cleared for Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-intent, android-geofence

I want to get notified when Google Play services data is cleared.

So, is there any Intent filter to listen for ?

I want to listen for this event so that i can re-register for geo-fences.
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED` intent.

Add a receiver to `AndroidManifest.xml` like you would for any intent:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".DataClearedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In your `DataClearedReceiver` you can now use:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED.equals(intent.getAction()) && intent.getData() != null) {
        if (data.getSchemeSpecificPart() == "com.google.android.gms") {
           // perform action
        }
    }
}
```